# Sql self join where not exists?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have a table something like the following:

```
name    | language | text  
-----------------------------
greet   | 1        | hello
greet   | 2        | bonjour
blue    | 1        | blue
blue    | 2        | bleu 
red     | 1        | red
green   | 1        | green
yellow  | 1        | yellow
```

I need to retrieve all the records which only exist for language number 1, so in the above example I should only have a list containing red, green and yellow. I don't really know much about sql joins so not sure what would be the best way to go about this? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE t.language = 1
AND NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
   WHERE t.name = t2.name
   AND ( t2.language IS NULL OR t2.language <> 1 )
)
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/813d9/1/0)</kbd>

I've included `t2.language IS NULL` to show you how to handle `NULL`-values, if it's a non-null column you only need `t2.language <> 1`.
This is the most readable and efficient approach that has no issues with NULL values. There are [others](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Answer (score 1):

Filter records using `NOT IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE LANGUAGE = 1
AND  NAME NOT IN
(
   SELECT NAME FROM TABLENAME 
   WHERE   LANGUAGE <> 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

using a jion

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM      TableName t1 
  left join TableName t2 
    on t2.name = t1.name 
   and t1.language =  1
   and t2.language <> 1
 where t2.name is null
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need a `JOIN` just use the `WHERE` keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM translationTable WHERE language = 1
```

Comment: which "only" exists for language 1 : this won't be managed by your code (greet and blue should not be retrieved, but will with the given code).